# Importing Blackberry 10 webworks app in QNX Momentics IDE

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, qnx, blackberry-qnx

I have a blackberry 10 webworks application by following this link ("https://developer.blackberry.com/htm...llo_world.html") . This application works fine and I have signed this app from command prompt using this command "blackberry-signer -storepass xxx path_to_bar file" and the application is signed successfully.
I got this message in Command line as " Info: bar signed"

But when I tried to verify my bar file by unzipping it i found an additional manifest.bbr file. when I package another blackberry 10 sample application in QNX momentics IDE , there is no such manifest.bbr file. Its getting signed perfectly.

Now, all I want is to port my Blackberry 10 webworks app from RippleSites folder to QNX momentics IDE and I want to sign the app from that IDE to get it signed perfectly.

How can I do this? can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I think you can't use QNX signer for webworks. You must use console signer

Answer (score 0):

If you've signed the app successfully via WebWorks then you're good to go. No need to question the "bar signed" output from the signer.

If you want to port your BlackBerry 10 app from web to native then you'll need to rewrite it using QML and possibly C++ depending on what features and/or APIs you're making use of.

Comment: The app is getting signed successfully. I get the "**Info: bar signed**" message too.... But why is that I am getting an additional **manifest.bbr** file?